# Error while installing ubuntu

Tags: installation, server

i have downloaded ubuntu 12.04 for windows laptop laptop and successfully burned into dvd and while installing the dvd iam getting this error:
"Kernel can't load and also error in cd" i have followed normal procedure to burn the dvd.

Comment: System specification please?  CPU, Amount of RAM, etc.

Comment: Also, was "and also error in cd" the exact words in the error message?

Comment: This points to a possibly bad download - the .iso might be corrupted. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes about how to check.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make bootable pendrive by makin iso file of ubnutand then install

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but I recommend editing this to provide a bit of information about how, or at least a link to some instructions.